# How to automate django dumpdata?

Tags: python, django

I am populating my DB locally and I want to dump that data to the production server with a script for all my apps.

I am trying to write a script that will do this...

```
$ source path/to/venv && python manage.py dumpdata app1 > file1.json
$ source path/to/venv && python manage.py dumpdata app2 > file2.json
...etc
```

I use fabric for my deploy script and I thought it would be nice to incorporate it in there, but the 'local' method in fabric doesn't seem to be able to do such a thing. the run command does, but IDK why.

I think it might have something to do with this...

> local is not currently capable of simultaneously printing and
>   capturing output, as run/sudo do. The capture kwarg allows you to
>   switch between printing and capturing as necessary, and defaults to
>   False. (http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/operations.html)

but I am not sure

I tried doing it with os.system n a separate python script as well but that didn't work either, both of them give me the same error which is...

```
sh: 1: source: not found
```

I have checked and double checked the path many times, I can't seem to figure it out. What do you think?

Comment: Run it as a cron job?

Comment: did you read my post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since '$ source' was the thing that could not be executed. I made a shell script, placed it in a directory and just executed that

```
source pathto/pyenv/bin/activate && python manage.py dumpdata quiz > data_dump/foo.json
source pathto/pyenv/bin/activate && python manage.py dumpdata main > data_dump/bar.json
source pathto/pyenv/bin/activate && python manage.py dumpdata study > data_dump/waz.json
```

and then in the fabric file...

```
def foobar():
    local('/pathto/foo.sh')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your script executes under the classic sh shell, not under bash.  "source" is a bash command; the classic import command is a period (like ". pathto/pyenv/bin/activate").  Or you could force bash with #!/bin/bash at the start of your script.